# Compound Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution

I have come across the following expression:
$$ T={m-y \choose \frac{m}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2}^{(m-y)}={m-y \choose \frac{m}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2}^{\frac{m}{2}}\dfrac{1}{2}^{\frac{m}{2}-y}$$
where $y$ is a binomial random variable with $m$ trials and probability $p$. 
Is this a compound Binomial distribution where the number of trials is a Binomial random variable?

Comment: To what are you referring?  $T$ as you have defined it is a random variable (provided $m$ is even)--it's not a "distribution."  Including $0$, it takes at most $m/2+2$ distinct values between $0$ and $1$.  Its distribution won't correspond to any recognizable distribution.  I suspect you might have mischaracterized something you read.

Comment: @whuber, I edited my question. this looks very similar to a Binomial distribution, except that the number of trial is a Binomial distribution. I thought maybe this would be  known distribution.

Comment: Suppose $m=4$, the simplest nontrivial case.  Then there are exactly three values of $y$ for which $T$ is nonzero: when $y=0$, $T=\binom{4-0}{4/2}2^{0-4}=6/16=3/8$, when $y=1$, $T=\binom{4-1}{4/2}2^{1-4}=3/8$, and when $y=2$, $T=\binom{4-2}{4/2}2^{2-4}=1/4$.  When $y$ is $0$ or $1$, $T$ is zero. Thus $T$ can take on *only* the values $3/8$, $1/4$, and $0$.  Obviously that's not a Binomial distribution, nor is it any "known" (i.e., named and cataloged) distribution, because all of those describe random variables with (continuous) real or integer values.

Comment: Can you clarify how you "have come across" the expression - I strongly suspect this was intended to be something like a conditional probability (of something) conditional on $y$, not a random variable defined as a transformation of $y$. Voting to close as unclear